# Javascript : Objects and multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have created one namespace object.

```
gf.jsObjects = {}
```

I want to hold the following data in the objects.

```
gf.jsObjects { obj1: [id: 1, name: "2"], ... ] obj2: [id: "1", name: "name"]}; or
gf.jsObjects { obj1: [1,'name'], ... ] obj2: [1,2],[1,'name'], ...};
```

I tried the following.

```
gf.jsObjects.obj1 = [];
gf.jsObjects.obj1 = [][]; //This one gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] "
var i = 0;
$.each(...) {
    gf.jsObjects.obj1[i].push(value1);
    gf.jsObjects.obj1[i].push(value2);
    i++;
});
```

It is not working. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is very unclear...

Comment: `[id: 1, name: "2"]` This is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `[i]`, use just `gf.jsObjects.obj1.push(value1);`.

Try this:

```
gf = {};
gf.jsObjects = [];
gf.jsObjects.obj1 = [];

var i = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    gf.jsObjects.obj1.push({'ID:': i, 'Name:': i});

};
console.log(gf.jsObjects.obj1);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amFsq/)

Or this:

```
gf = {};
gf.jsObjects = {};
gf.jsObjects.obj1 = [];

var i = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    gf.jsObjects.obj1.push({'ID': i, 'Name': i});

};
console.log(gf.jsObjects.obj1);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amFsq/1/)

Comment: I want multidimensional array. for every array index, i want to hold to values. the id and the equivalent name

Comment: Thanks. That is what i was trying! `0: Array[2] 0: "ID: 0" 1: "value_0"` There is two values in every Array. The index is 0 and 1. Can we name it id and name?

Comment: @MaheshKumar, sure. Change the names, I added another option, not sure wich one you prefer.